# Limiting the subquery with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, relational-database

I have defined few models in SQLAlchemy:

```
class Location(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Location'
    __table_args__ = {u'schema': 'Location'}

    Unit_id = Column(ForeignKey(u'Structure.Definition.Unit_id', ondelete=u'RESTRICT', onupdate=u'CASCADE'), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    Timestamp = Column(DateTime, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    Latitude = Column(Float)
    Longitude = Column(Float)


class Definition(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Definition'
    __table_args__ = {u'schema': 'Structure'}

    Unit_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    Name = Column(String(90))

    Location = relationship(u'Location')
```

And I have my query:

```
sub = DBSession.query(Location.Unit_id, func.max(Location.Timestamp).label('latest_timestamp')).\
    filter(Location.Latitude != None, Location.Longitude != None).\
    group_by(Location.Unit_id).\
    subquery()

res = DBSession.query(Definition).\
    join((sub, sub.c.Unit_id == Definition.Unit_id)).\
    all()
```

The result of my query is few `Definition` objects with all possible `Location` for each one of them. However, I'd like to make a query to get all `Definition` rows, but only the **LAST** row from `Locations` table for each of `Definition` row.

What would be the best way to make my query, taking in account that `Location` table has hundreds of thousands of rows in it already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you do not seem to use the `latest_timestamp` from your subquery at all, which looks like a complete waste. Also, your query returns **only** `Definition` instances.

Try this instead:

```
res = DBSession.query(Definition, Location).\
    join(Location, Definition.Location).\
    join((sub, and_(sub.c.Unit_id == Definition.Unit_id, 
                    sub.c.latest_timestamp == Location.Timestamp)).\
    all()


for defi, loca in res:
    print(defi, loca)
```

*Note: I would prefer `locations` instead of `Location` as a name of the relationship.*